# SQL Join Favorites List Returns Wrong Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm attempting to do a relatively simple MySQL query where I return the favorite posts added by the user.  However, my only error is the name of the post int he favorites returns as the user who added the favorite and not the actual user who wrote the post.  Below is my database for the favorites and then the query below.  Please let me know if you need more information from me as I'd be happy to help in any way.

[image]

```
$username = $_GET['username'];

//initial query
$query = "SELECT body, latitude, longitude, (SELECT username FROM Users WHERE Users.IDUser=Favorites.IDUser) AS username, (SELECT profile_picture FROM Users WHERE Users.IDUser=Favorites.IDUser) AS profile_picture, filename, post_date FROM Posts, Favorites WHERE Posts.IDPosts = Favorites.IDPosts AND Favorites.IDUser=(Select IDUser FROM Users WHERE Users.username=:username) ORDER BY post_date DESC";

$query_params = array(
        ':username' => $username
    );
```

DB diagram:

![enter image description here][2]

Comment: Post your entire schema.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: test your query directly on the mysql!

Comment: Please format your query. As it stands, it is impossible to read. Until then I vote for closing as "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: I did and it works but seems to only return with my username for the other person's post.

Comment: How would you suggest I format the query to your liking?

Comment: Please see the above diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You should have uploaded your database schema for this question and you should've formatted your query to be more readable but anyway I don't know if that's correct, I could not tried it but try and please let me know if it is wrong (I don't know what I'm doing because I cannot see the schema and I don't know what are you trying to do)

`SELECT body, latitude, longitude, Users.username, 
        Users.profile_picture, filename, post_date
 FROM Posts, Favorites, Users
 WHERE Users.username=:username AND Posts.IDPosts = Favorites.IDPosts 
       AND Favorites.IDUser = Users.IDUser ORDER BY post_date DESC`

**Edit**

```
 SELECT Users.profile_picture, Users.username, latitude, 
        longitude, post_date, filename
 FROM Users 
 JOIN Posts ON Posts.IDUser = Users.IDUser
 JOIN Favorites ON Posts.IDPosts = Favorites.IDPosts
     WHERE Users.username=:username 
           AND Users.IDUser = Posts.IDUser
           AND Posts.IDPosts = Posts.IDPosts
```

Comment: Close but it will still show the wrong username for say the "Test from Mburg" where it is a different author.  I will post a diagram of the database.

Comment: See the above diagram.

Comment: Try again please I did not make any test though

Comment: It does the same thing.  It'll only show the device user's username for their favorites including posts not originally theirs, not the username of the marked favorites from other users.